# Finding the file that is on a bad block on a HFS+ volume (debugfs for HFS+)

Tags: macos, mac, bad-sectors, hfs+, bad-blocks

I have a drive in our iMac that has bad blocks, as booting from an Ubuntu 11.10 live CD and using `ddrescue -f /dev/sda /dev/null` finds them.  I'd like to get the drive to remap them by writing to the blocks, say using `hdparm --write-sector`, but I don't want to do this without knowing what's in those blocks and finding the file that owns them, so I can restore the file from another source.

I found [fileXray](https://web.archive.org/web/20200103162305/https://filexray.com/) but don't feel like spending $79 to map a block to a file and [hfsdebug](https://web.archive.org/web/20210616020646/http://osxbook.com/software/hfsdebug/) has been taken offline.  Are there suggestions on a tool or technique to use?

I looked at all the Ubuntu HFS+ packages to see if they could provide this info but nothing jumped out at me.

BTW, I used Disk Utility to erase the empty space, but it didn't get any of the bad blocks to be remapped, according to `smartctl -A`.

Comment: Back it up with Time Machine, erase the disk, and reinstall.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are running Lion, `man fsck_hfs` and look at the `-B` option which says it will print files given a list of block numbers. Note: I had to include `-n -f` on the command to force a check, otherwise it just reported `*** NO MATCH ***` for all the blocks in my list.

Also, before attempting to overwrite a block, I'd want to develop and run some test to verify the mapping is correct between block numbers reported by `ddrescue` and those used by `fsck_hfs` and `hdparm`.

Comment: Passing `-l` to `fsck_hfs` seems like a safer way if the filesystem is currently mounted.

Comment: I also had to add `-b 512` since, given a plain file (the output of ddrescue) it was unable to automatically determine a blocksize to work in. So, in total `fsck_hfs -n -f -b 512 -B badblocks.txt <file>`, where badblocks.txt was the hex offsets from the ddrescue map.txt divided by 512. Presumably one would also need to subtract off the offset of the start of the partition, but I had actually already done ddrescue on only one partition, rather than the whole raw device.

Comment: > before attempting to overwrite a block, I'd want to develop and run some test to verify the mapping is correct

I was also able to check this - I picked a file with fairly distinctive contents, and used grep --text --byte-offset 'whatever' partition.img, to find a plain byte offset where that data appeared. fsck_hfs correctly Identified the filename, so its block numbering is indeed just offset divided by 512 (or whatever -b <blocksize> was used).